# Unique risk neutral measure for Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion, risk-neutral-measure

For a standard geometric Brownian motion model of stock prices:
$$ dS = a S dt + \sigma S dZ$$
we can transform the process to be under risk neutral measure:
$$ dS = r S dt + \sigma S d \tilde{Z}$$
and from the references I found, this risk neutral measure is "unique".

If we make a transform, say
$$ dS = r S dt + \tau S d \hat{Z}$$
where $\tau$ is different from $\sigma$, this equation gives the correct price of stock. but Black-Scholes equation will fail as we have changed volatility.

However, for a discrete model, e.g. a tree model, if there are $n$ states of world, then we need $n-1$ assets plus cash to uniquely pin down risk neutral measure.

**Question**:The Brownian motion model in effect has infinite number of states and only one asset, then where does uniqueness of risk neutral measure come from?

Answer (score 3):

The uniqueness of the risk-neutral measure comes from the abundance of  tradable assets. Let $B_t$ be the money-market account at time $t$. Let $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ be two risk-neutral measures. Then, for any tradable asset $X$ with maturity $T$,
\begin{align*}
E^{Q_1}\left(\frac{X_T}{B_T}\right) &= E^{Q_2}\left(\frac{X_T}{B_T}\right)\\
&=\frac{X_0}{B_0}.
\end{align*}
For any $A\in \mathcal{F}_T$, we define an asset with payoff 
$$\mathbb{I}_{A} B_T.$$
Note that, this deal may not be exchange traded, however, it can be made over-the-counter. Then
\begin{align*}
Q_1(A) &= E^{Q_1}\left(\frac{\mathbb{I}_{A} B_T}{B_T}\right)\\
&= E^{Q_2}\left(\frac{\mathbb{I}_{A} B_T}{B_T}\right)\\
&= Q_2(A).
\end{align*}
That is, $Q_1=Q_2$.

Comment: But did B-S model assume the indicator function asset is traded? The original proof involves replicating time differential of option with differentials of cash and stock and invoking non-arbitrage.

Comment: @user3785097, $E(\mathbb{I}_{A} \mid \mathcal{F}_t)$ is a martingale, on which the differential is taken.

Answer (score 1):

essentially it comes down the fact that the dyadic quadratic variation of $W_t$ is $t$ with probability 1 and any measure change has to preserve this fact. Changing volatility would violate this invariance.

Comment: any *equivalent* measure change

Answer (score 1):

Let M denote the number of underlying traded assets in
the model excluding the risk free asset, and let R denote the number of random
sources. Generically we then have the following relations:
1. The model is arbitrage free if and only if M ≤ R.
2. The model is complete if and only if M ≥ R.
3. The model is complete and arbitrage free if and only if M = R.
Black Scholes Model is Complete and arbitrage free then risk-neutral measure is unique.